# Why ProgressBar does not displaying the current value / does not refreshing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

I use the following code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            progressBar1.Step = 1;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                progressBar1.PerformStep();
                label1.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

**But,** even after `this.Refresh();` the value of the progress bar does not updated. Only the label updated. When the labels already show 100, for progress bar stil have more few steps to finish.
What i do wrong?
why the value of the progress bar is not updated?
How i should do it correct?

Answer (score 1):

are you using Task, async, await? this is a common sample in winforms

see [IProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)

```
public void DoWork(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    // This method is executed in the context of
    // another thread 
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
    {
        //DO something

        // Use progress to notify UI thread that progress has
        // changed
        if (progress != null)
            progress.Report((j + 1) * 100 / 100000);
    }
}

private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar.Step = 1;

    var progress = new Progress<int>(v =>
    {
        // This lambda is executed in context of UI thread,
        // so it can safely update form controls
        progressBar.Value = v;
    });

    // Run operation in another thread
    await Task.Run(() => DoWork(progress));
}
```

Comment: No. This not the case, I working with sequential code.

Comment: i cant guess that with your lines of code..its the way to use progress bar..thats is not functional?

Comment: i am not sure you could with the same thread without refactoring your code..but without code difficult to do more

Comment: I updated the question and added the code as you requested.

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code and it worked fine for me, did you add any special properties to your progress bar?

Assuming that it is all there is to it, try removing it and adding a new one without adjusting its default properties, you can also try adjusting the value in your `Thread.Sleep()` so that you can see the progress more

Comment: For you, with the above code, the progress bar and the number in the label are sync? when the label.text show 100 the progress bar is full also in the same time?

Comment: And no, i didn't edit any properties in the progress bar.